# VSCode Change Default Terminal from Windows PowerShell to Node

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

How can I change my default terminal from Powershell to Node in VS Code? After installing the latest version of VS Code, default terminal has been changed from Node to Powershell. I want to run my angular application using Node terminal. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>comma</kbd>
2. Search for `terminal integrated shell windows`
3. Type in the path of your default terminal

You can also add line `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "path/to/shell"` to your global settings.json file.

Comment: Just added cmd.exe path. Once I execute a command it will automatically open up Node terminal and works perfectly. Thanks for the answer.